# How to create a content type in drupal 7 to display the latest post

Tags: view, drupal-7, position, drupal-views, content-type

I have created a content type for Events with fields Event Date and Event description, these events are linked to a seperate page. Now i want the latest event to appear on the top position of the page and older ones below. How to achieve this?  Please help at the earliest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that using views module. I you don't have it, it is worth installing since you will use it a lot as you get hold of it.

Create a view showing fields of your content type event. In the view you can create a page which is useful for your case. You can custom your page url so it is easily added to a menu or link.

One you bring the fields you need, you can filter the view to show you only the field of the content type and arrange by date added.